# EhCache using too much Heap Memory to store values

Tags: java, ehcache

I have used EhCache to cache 2.5 Gb of data. I have 32 files with varying size but total data volume is 2.5 Gb. I ran my code using 12G Heap memory but entire data set couldn't be accommodate in 12G of data, it overflows to disk. Could you please tell me what's wrong in configuration or EhCache always takes that much memory. All the caches I put Integer as key and List as value (record of a delimited file)

JVM Arguments used `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe  -server -d64 -Xms12G -Xmx12G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

Below are the code snippet I have used for Cache

```
//Spring Configuration
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown",name="batchCache")
public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
    DiskStoreConfiguration diskStoreConfiguration = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
    diskStoreConfiguration.setPath("C:\\DiskCache");

    net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
    config.setName("NAV_BATCH");
    config.addDiskStore(diskStoreConfiguration);
    //config.setMaxBytesLocalHeap(MemoryUnit.GIGABYTES.toBytes(10));
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager mgr = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    mgr.clearAll();
    return mgr;
}

//Code to Obtain Cache manager
private CacheManager cacheManager = (CacheManager) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("batchCache");

//Class level copy of Cache
private Cache cache;

protected Cache getCache(){
    if(null == cache){
        Cache managerCache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
        if(null == managerCache){
            cache = createCache();
        }else{
            cache = managerCache;
        }
    }
    return cache;
}

//Key is Integer and Values is List of String always
protected void putListRecordsInCache(Object key,List<Object> values){
    Element element = new Element(key, values);
    getCache().put(element);
}

public List<T> getValues(Object key){
    Element e  = getCache().get(key);
    List<T> dataList = new LinkedList<>();
    if(null == e){
        return dataList;
    }

    List<String> lines = (List<String>) e.getObjectValue();

    for(String line:lines){
        T t = getMapper().convertValuesToObject(line, null);
        dataList.add(t);
    }

    return dataList;
}

private Cache createCache(){
    Cache managerCache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    if(null == managerCache){
        managerCache = new Cache(cacheConfig(cacheName) );
        //managerCache = (Cache) cacheManager.addCacheIfAbsent(managerCache);
        cacheManager.addCache(managerCache);
    }
    return managerCache;
}

private CacheConfiguration cacheConfig(String name) {
    CacheConfiguration config = new CacheConfiguration();
    config.name(name)

    .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU")
    .eternal(true)
    .pinning(new PinningConfiguration().store(Store.LOCALMEMORY))
    .logging(false)
    .sizeOfPolicy(new SizeOfPolicyConfiguration().maxDepth(100000).maxDepthExceededBehavior("CONTINUE"))
    .persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP))
    .statistics(true);
    ;

    long size = -1;
    try {
        size = Files.size(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(getDataFileLocation(), getFileName()));
        //System.out.println(new Date()+",Size of file "+getDataFileLocation()+"/"+getFileName()+" is "+size+" bytes");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(size > 0){
        long cachesize = size*4;
        config.maxBytesLocalHeap(cachesize, MemoryUnit.BYTES);
    }else{

        if(isValueGloballyCached){
            config.maxBytesLocalHeap(100, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES);
        }else{
            config.maxBytesLocalHeap(500, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES);
        }
    }


    return config;
}
```

> Below are the Memory and CPU Profile screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you calculate the space of 2.5 gb data? If you have a lot of short strings, the java string object overhad adds. Read [memory usage of string objects](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml).

Comment: 2.5 Gb is total cumulative size of files. Each line is stored as a String in EhCache

Comment: Which charset is used in those files? What charset is used to read the files? How many lines (String objects) do you have. How many lines does the biggest file have?

Comment: Biggest file with 594 Mb size has 10364370 lines. Character Set is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not "Ehcache is using to much memory". The question is more like "caching huge files in a memory in an efficient way".

Furthermore, you want to have random access to every line of the file.

So way is Ehcache so mem greedy?
The java string object adds 38 bytes to every string you want to store + 16 bytes for your `Integer` key (8 for houskeeping + 4 for int = rounds to 16 byte). This adds ca. 550mb to your biggest file for a 32 bit environment. This gets even worse in a 64 bit environment.

I guess, your add about 1GB object overhead to your 594 mb file and I did not consider the `Element` object ehcache uses. If you look into that Object you get a pretty good idea where the memory is wasted.

So, I think I made clear why your 2.5 GB files uses so much memory.

A possible solution: Suppose you can use a `Singleton` to cache the data.

I would store the text of a file in one `String` object and create a separate `int[]` (not `Integer[]`) array that holds the offset for every line.

So getting the text for line `1000` would be:

```
//    text of the the file
String text;
//    int array of offset.
int[] offset;
// todo: check if there is line 1000

int start = offset[999];
int end = offset.length > 1000 ? offset[1000] : text.length();
String line1000 = text.substring(start, end);
```

If you follow that approach, you get a string and an int array for every file. The `String` object holds text and the the array holds the offsets.

Comment: Thanks Peter, you answer my question why it is taking so much memory. Could you please give me some more code snippet to implement your solution. Also are you suggesting me to use -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<xx>g for your solution

Answer (score 1):

I have also had trouble with ehcache using (way) too much memory as well as "MappedByteBufferSource Async Flush Thread" errors on very simple test examples.  Depending on how much functionality you need, I would personally use a [BigArrayList](https://github.com/dselent/BigArrayList/wiki).  It can be used just like a regular ArrayList and will handle all the I/O from disk to memory for you with an LRU policy. You can store your lists of objects as elements in the BigArrayList and operate on it as you would a normal ArrayList.  You may have to experiment with how many elements you want to store in memory depending on the size of the elements and your available memory.  The advantages are that it is easy to use and actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one attribute is there in the ehcache.xml which is maxBytesLocalOffheap, that might be useful in your case.

Please go through
http://blog.terracotta.org/2015/04/13/ehcache-storage-tier-model-with-offheap/

If your ehcache version is below 2.3 than you need to run manual thread to look the expired content so that you have enough space in heap.

i.e.background thread doing the getKeysWithExpiryCheck() on a regular interval.

Comment: Thanks but BigMemory solution isn't free. So This is not a viable solution for us.

Comment: I am using ehcache 2.9 even I have to run a separate thread to evict expired elements from heap, Ehcache doesn't do it by itslef.